# How to specify value of AlgorithmParameterSpec in java, for encryption and Decryption puropose, in DES

Tags: java, encryption, des, secret-key, javax

My qustion is about how should I specify the custom value of AlgorithmParameterSpec in the below program? So that I could use the exact same output value for two different programs, one of which is Server and other is Client. Like I have used the fixed value for Key Generation, I want the same for this AlgorithmParameterSpec.
Client Code Snippet

```
   ....
   String desKey = "0123456789abcdef"; // value from user  
   byte[] keyBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(desKey);
   SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("DES");
   SecretKey key = factory.generateSecret(new DESKeySpec(keyBytes));


   AlgorithmParameterSpec paramSpec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
   ....
```

Both client and server are on different pcs and are connected on same LAN. However I dont want to send any file from one to another, and neither do I want to write the value of that parameter from client into any file and use it in server. That has already caused too much problems. Is there a way to do this? Or I have to send this generated value from client to server using readUTF and writeUTF?

Comment: You want a fixed key and a fixed IV, why even bother encrypting it in the first place?

Comment: @JamesKPolk I am new to this stuff and so I want to use a fixed value for trial purpose for encryption and decryption, I don't want to get into hassle currently with the errors that occur during encryption of IV value and sending it  to server, so that both use the same value, because I tried it with secret key and there is this error
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException : Illegal base character`
and this too
`javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException : Input length must be multiple of 16 when decrypting with padded cipher`

Answer (score 0):

1. Original DES aka single-DES has been broken since last century, and should not be used.
2. In Java, instantiating plain `DES` like that defaults to `DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding` (in general Java treats PKCS5 padding as including PKCS7). ECB does not use an IV, and DES has no other parameters, so a java `Cipher` object for DES/ECB does not need or use any type of parameters object. However, in most applications, ECB mode even with a good cipher (not DES) is insecure and should not be used.
3. If you change to a more secure mode that *does* use an IV, like CTR CBC OFB CFB, or better in most applications but only supported in j8+ GCM, then `IvParameterSpec` is indeed the correct type to use. 
   However, with modes that use an IV, using a fixed or otherwise duplicated IV is almost always insecure, so you must have a process that provides a unique IV for each encryption and the corresponding decryption(s).

   This is often done by choosing a random IV when encrypting and transmitting and/or storing it along with the ciphertext (sometimes simply as the first part of the ciphertext) to be used when decrypting, but other designs that accomplish the same thing are possible. For CTR-based modes including GCM, especially when applied to a stream of traffic between the same parties, using a (scaled) counter provides uniqueness. For CBC the IVs must not only be unique but unpredictable; random is usually easiest for this but it is possible to use an encrypted counter.
4. Both key and IV (when used) should actually be bits not characters. However it is often convenient to represent them in characters using hex (as you did) or base64. Such character representations can be transmitted and received by a huge variety of methods, of which `DataInput/OutputStream` or `ObjectInput/OutputStream` is one among many. There are also many ways to transmit bits (binary) on all networks used in this century (although back in the 1970s and 1980s this was often problematical). Choosing among these may depend on what else your programs are doing and in particular whether they already use things like HTTP, XML, JSON, etc.